# Sometime scope variable not getting set

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, intervals

This seems pretty strange to me but I hope there's someone that has come across this before and point me in the right direction.

I have a variable being set in scope within an $interval and the value is sometimes "sticking" and sometimes not.

```
someInterval = $interval(function() {
SomeFactory.getsomething($scope.highestnumber)
    .then(function(response) {
        if (response.number > $scope.highestnumber)
            $scope.highestnumber = response.number;
    });
}, 30000);
```

Most of the time this works - $scope.highestnumber is set with the updated value and 30 seconds later getSomething() is called passing the updated value.

However, every now and then (and I wish I could duplicate on demand), $scope.highestnumber is set with a new value but getSomething() is called with the value it had before the update executed. I have verified it by catching the value of $scope.highestnumber after it's been set to the new value, and then checking what's being passed into getSomething() on the next cycle.

So the sequence would be...

- $scope.highestnumber = 10
- getsomething(10) called
- returns response.number = 11
- $scope.highestnumber set to 11 (verified)
- getSomething(10) called 30 seconds later

Comment: If your scope property doesn't have a '.' (that's a dot) in it that could possibly be your issue. See here: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/14/nested-scopes-in-angularjs.html

Comment: That's an interesting article but doesn't seem to apply here since it's all happening in the same scope (no child scopes).

Comment: I can't seem to replicate the behavior using similar code in a Plunker. Can you see you if you can modify it to better demonstrate the problem? http://plnkr.co/edit/b9fkPDUD4JsPaGqU12VX